# Splitting of data from the dates of data available in R

Tags: r, dplyr

Suppose I have data as follows,

```
Col Date
a   1/1/2016
a   1/2/2016
a   1/3/2016
a   1/4/2016
a   1/5/2016
a   1/6/2016
a   1/7/2016
a   1/8/2016
a   1/9/2016
a   1/10/2016
a   1/11/2016
a   1/12/2016
a   1/13/2016
a   1/19/2016
a   1/20/2016
a   1/21/2016
a   1/22/2016
a   1/23/2016
a   1/28/2016
a   1/29/2016
a   1/30/2016
b   1/1/2016
b   1/2/2016
b   1/3/2016
b   1/4/2016
b   1/11/2016
b   1/12/2016
b   1/13/2016
b   1/14/2016
b   1/15/2016
c   1/1/2016
c   1/5/2016
```

I want to split the data by the dates of the data that is available. Suppose I want to know which col has 30 days data, A alone should be returned. If I want to know which has 15 days data, a,b should be returned and similarly 5 days data, the entire dataset should be returned. I am not sure how to approach this problem. Can anybody help me or give some idea how to do this?

Update :

```
subset1 = data.frame()
waste = data.frame()

for(i in 1:length(unique(data$col))){
    group <- data %>% 
      filter(col == unique(l$col)[i])
    p = max(group$date) - min(group$date) 
    if(p>0)
      subset1 = rbind(subset,group)
    else
      waste = rbind(waste,group)
    }
```

These are my tryings. But I am getting the following error,

```
 Error in rbind(deparse.level, ...) : 
  numbers of columns of arguments do not match
```

Is there a more sufficient way to do this? My data is huge. Any comments would help.

Comment: Group your data.frame by `Col`, count the rows, select the rows with a count above `n`

Comment: @thelatemail that could give me same count for 5 days and 20 days as well right? There may be 5 days from 1 - 5 of the month and there may be 1,5,10,15,30 and that would also have 5 as count. So there I face a problem

Comment: Are you looking for the range of days covered by `Date`?

Comment: @CactusWoman yes. I want to split the data based on the range of date covered by each entry in col

Comment: where did you get stuck? did you format the dates?

Comment: @rawr yes I did. I have updated my findings. Can you help me in finding out the problem?

Comment: @rawr should I create another dataframe of the same structure of l? to make this work?

Comment: You can define an index such as `indx <- with(df, tapply(as.Date(Date, "%m/%d/%Y"), Col, FUN = function(x) max(x) - min(x))) + 1`, then define your desired `n`, such as `n <- 15`, then `df[df$Col %in% names(indx[indx >= n]), ]` should work.

Comment: Using `dplyr` (per your tag), this could be something like `df %>% group_by(Col) %>% summarise(Range = diff(range(as.Date(Date, "%m/%d/%Y"))) + 1) %>% filter(Range >= n) %>% inner_join(df)`

Comment: @DavidArenburg It seems to work. Checking my data. In the meantime can you post this as an answer?